# How to subset a column by triplicates?

Tags: r

I am wondering how to subset my data based on the appearance of triplicates in a column.

```
t <- c(1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5,5,6,6,7,7,7,8,8)

mydf <- data.frame(t, 1:18)
```

I want to be able to grab only the rows that correspond to a triplicate in column t, so that I can form a new dataframe of only those rows. That would look like this where p is the vector of rows I'm looking for:

```
p <- c(9,10,11,14,15,16)

myidealdf[p,]
```

Sorry if this isn't clear, it's my first post

Comment: Sure this is a duplicate, but can't find it: `mydf[with(mydf, ave(seq_along(t),t,FUN=length)==3),]`

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3919205/using-r-delete-rows-when-a-value-repeated-less-than-3-times

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do it

```
keeps <- unique(t)[table(as.factor(t)) == 3]
keeps <- t %in% keeps
mydf <- mydf[keeps, ]
```

Comment: you beat me! - a slightly simpler version: `mydf[mydf$t %in% which(table(mydf$t) == 3), ]`

Comment: Finally! :) Bear in mind that your version will only work if t is a monotone increasing sequence starting at 1 (due to the `which` call).

Comment: It might be safer to convert `t` to a factor first, then it's just `mydf[t %in% levels(t)[table(t) == 3], ]`

Answer (score 0):

Using `rle` function.

```
which(t %in% with(rle(t), values[lengths==3]))
[1]  9 10 11 14 15 16
```