# Replacing values in column that occur less than x times

Tags: r, dataframe

How can I replace all values in my column, that occur less than 3 times? Let's say this is my column (from a data frame):

```
>df$example
 aa
 aa
 aa
 bb
 bb
 cc
 cc
 cc
```

Result should be (if I replace them with text `replaced`) :

```
>df$example
 aa
 aa
 aa
 replaced
 replaced 
 cc
 cc
 cc
```

I saw another solution ([using R - delete rows when a value repeated less than 3 times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3919205/using-r-delete-rows-when-a-value-repeated-less-than-3-times)) but that was only deleting the rows. I also tried it with a table. I hope to avoid a for loop, because I will apply this on a huge data frame.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In base R you can use `ave`,

```
with(df, ave(example, example, FUN = function(i) replace(i, length(i) < 3, 'replaced')))
#[1] "aa"       "aa"       "aa"       "replaced" "replaced" "cc"       "cc"       "cc"
```

**NOTE:** Make sure that your column is set `as.character()`, i.e. NOT factor

Answer (score 1):

Another one liner in base R using `table` where we count the number of occurrence for each column value and change those values to "Replaced" which occur less than 3 times.

```
df$example[with(df, example %in% unique(example)[table(example) < 3])] <- "Replaced"

df
#   example
#1       aa
#2       aa
#3       aa
#4 Replaced
#5 Replaced
#6       cc
#7       cc
#8       cc
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this much efficient.

```
setDT(df)
df[df$example==names(which(table(df$example) < 3)),example:="replaced"]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df$example[df$example %in% names(which(table(df$example) < 3L))] = "replaced"
```

---

### Explanation

We use `table` to count the occurrences in `df$example`. Then, for the ones occurring less than three times, we get their name with `names` and match the original vector to these with `"=="`, using the matches as indices. Then we assign the value `"replaced"` for this sub-array.

---

### If `df$example` is a `factor`

You could cast it with `as.character` then recast with `as.factor`. Or, alternatively, do this:

```
levels(df$example) = c(levels(df$example), "replaced")
df$example[df$example%in% names(which(table(df$example) < 3L))] = "replaced"
df$example= factor(df$example)
```

We basically add a new level `"replaced"` in advance, and in the last line we remove non-existing labels from the factor, effectively removing the replaced levels.